# How to select Distinct values from sqlite database using SqlAlchemmy

Tags: java, python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Need  to select distinct values from sqlite database using Sql alchemmy,This is my code

```
device = Device.query.distinct(Device.device_id)
```

This is selecting all the rows from th table and ignores the distinct condition.what is the issue with my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the distinct `device_id`s from the table, you must explicitly select only the device_id:

```
device = db.session.query(Device.device_id).distinct()
```